# Unable to display piechart for Accounts per country in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, soql

I am trying to pull number of Accounts for every country in a pie chart using Visualforce, but no results in the page -

Here is my code, any help is appreciated -

```
public class PieChartControllerTest1 {
public PieChartControllerTest1 ()
{
}

public List<AggregateResult> getAccountCountry()
{
    AggregateResult[] result = [SELECT COUNT(Name) cnt, BillingCountry FROM Account GROUP BY BillingCountry];
    return result;
}

}
```

visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="PieChartControllerTest1" title="Pie Chart">
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Account By Country">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:chart height="450" width="750" data="{!AccountCountry}">
<apex:pieSeries labelField="Count" dataField="cnt">
<apex:chartLabel display="rotate" field="cnt"/>
</apex:pieSeries>
</apex:chart>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated Code!!

```
public class pieChartAccountCtrl {
    public pieChartAccountCtrl (){
    }

    public List<AggregateResult> getAccountCountry()
    {
        AggregateResult[] result = [SELECT COUNT(Name) cnt, BillingCountry FROM Account WHERE BillingCountry != null GROUP BY BillingCountry];
        return result;
    }

}
```

And Vf Page code is :

```
<apex:page controller="pieChartAccountCtrl" title="Pie Chart">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account By Country">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:chart height="450" width="750" data="{!AccountCountry}">
                    <apex:pieSeries labelField="BillingCountry" dataField="cnt">
                        <apex:chartLabel display="rotate" field="cnt"/>
                    </apex:pieSeries>
                </apex:chart>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Hope this will help you and if it is then don't forget to mark it as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Hi Pratibha, I think there are some account records with null value in
>   BillingCountry in your org, so use a where clause so that only those
>   records having some value in BillingCountry will be queried.

```
AggregateResult[] result = [SELECT COUNT(Name) cnt, BillingCountry FROM Account WHERE BillingCountry != null GROUP BY BillingCountry];

/*****In VF Page*****/
<apex:pieSeries labelField="BillingCountry" dataField="cnt">
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: As per Keith's suggestion I modified the code line in my answer for VF page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nebula's fix, you also need to ensure that both names in the `apex:pieSeries` match the names returned by the query. For the non-aggregated field you can just use the field name:

```
<apex:pieSeries labelField="BillingCountry" dataField="cnt">
```

For aggregated fields its best to use an alias as you already have done for "cnt".